# Ubuntu 20.04 Battery not charging when in hibernate mode

Tags: kernel, power-management, battery, hibernate

Until Ubuntu 19.10 all went fine, but when updating to Ubuntu 20.04, and thus the 5.4 Linux kernel, my battery does no longer charge in hibernation mode (it does charge when the laptop is on or off).

Tried to change the BIOS to switch between modern (output voltage through usb-c to charge devices even during hibenation) and classic hibernate, but that makes no difference.

Any hints on where to start looking will be largely appreciated!

For information: HP Spectre X360 13"